# R: Apply different sliding means on tibble columns

Tags: r

let's say I have this dataframe

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(ParameterID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                    2, 2, 2, 2),
                    Time= c(as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:05:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:10:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:15:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:20:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:25:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:30:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:05:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:10:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:30:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 11:30:00")),
                    value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4)) %>% arrange(Time)
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   ParameterID Time                value
         <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl>
 1           1 2022-01-01 10:05:00     1
 2           2 2022-01-01 10:05:00     1
 3           1 2022-01-01 10:10:00     2
 4           2 2022-01-01 10:10:00     2
 5           1 2022-01-01 10:15:00     3
 6           1 2022-01-01 10:20:00     4
 7           1 2022-01-01 10:25:00     5
 8           1 2022-01-01 10:30:00     6
 9           2 2022-01-01 10:30:00     3
10           2 2022-01-01 11:30:00     4
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following. Starting with the first observed Time, e.g. `2022-01-01 10:05:00`, I want to compute the `mean`, `max` and `min` of each parameter `1` and `2` after every **15 minutes**. So, at first at **10:20**, then **10:35** and so on...

The peculiarity, however, is that whenever the statistics are computed over **parameter 1**, the observation of the **last 15 minutes** should be considered. However, whenever statistics are computed over **parameter 2**, observations of the last **30 minutes** should be considered. Example:

**Point of observation: 2022-01-01 10:30:00**

- Statistics on `ParameterID 1` should include data of Parameter 1 from `10:15:00 - 10:30:00`.
- Statistics on `ParameterID 2` should include data of Parameter 2 from `10:00:00 - 10:30:00`.

Any ideas on an approach that is scalable to about 50 different parameters and lots of rows?

Comment: FYI: significant code-golf (and readability): change `c(as.POSIXct(.), as.POSIXct(.), ...)` to `as.POSIXct(c("2022-01-01 10:05:00", "2022-01-01 10:10:00"), ...)`.

Comment: First you say *"after every 15 minutes"*, then you say 15 or 30 for the different parameters, it seems you are contradicting yourself. When you're editing your question to clear up that wording, please add a column to your `df` that provides the expected output given this data. Thanks!